# EventingBasicConsumer: max number of threads

Tags: .net, multithreading, rabbitmq

What is the easiest way to control the maximum number of working threads when implementing RabbitMQ(.NET) consumer that uses EventingBasicConsumer?

As much as I understand at the moment by default there will be as many threads as many messages come in. If consuming operation opens a database connection for example then the max number of threads should be under control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a [consumer prefetch limit](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) to limit the number of unacknowledged messages that your consumer is allowed to have.

if you want to limit the number of threads to 1, for example, you would set a prefetch limit of 1 for that consumer.

note that you need to be in acknowledge mode for this to work, where you have to explicitly ack a message when you are done processing it.